# Google closure compiler, JSC_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY issue with mixin/extend

Tags: javascript, build, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, google-closure-compiler

The code below throws a warning/error when compiled with google closure compiler advanced mode.

> *JSC_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY: Property getJerseyNumber never defined on player*

Any ideas how we can fix this?

```
var getDetails = {
    getJerseyNumber: function() {
    return Math.random();
    }
};

/**
 * @param {Object} source
 * @param {Object} delta
 */
function mixIn(source, delta) {
    for (var i in delta) {
        source[i] = delta[i];
    }
}
/**
 *  @type  {{name: string , sport: string}}
 */
var player = {
    name: 'Tom Brady',
    sport: 'Football'
};

mixIn(player, /** @lends {player} */ getJerseyNumber);

alert(player.getJerseyNumber());
```

Using @lends work with object literals only. So adding this line will work, but any other ideas?

```
mixIn(player, /** @lends {player} */ {
    getJerseyNumber: function() {
        return Math.random();
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Closure documentation](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler),

> **@lends**
>
> Indicates that the keys of an object literal should be treated as properties of some other object. *This annotation should only appear on object literals.*

This is described in more detail by [jsdoc-toolkit](https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagLends).

---

For your example, I would use classes for common behavior.

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @param {string} name
 * @param {string} sport
 */
var Player = function(name, sport) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sport = sport;
};

Player.prototype.getJerseyNumber = function() {
    return Math.random();
};

var player = new Player('Tom Brady', 'Football');

alert(player.getJerseyNumber());
```

Of course, I imagine your example has some additional complexity, but without code to represent that complexity, I can only guess what that is.

You may be after the proposed (but as yet nonexistant) [@mixin](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=250) annotation.

Comment: The code sample provided is a good demonstration to fix the above issue, but basically i was looking for a way to have the compiler recognize multiple mixins. This is a handy construct for JS programming and is being used quite a lot (one popular code base using this is jquery). Looks like this will have to wait till this mixin feature lands in google closure compiler.